# Is there a summary of Code of Conduct changes?

Tags: discussion

When a company (e.g. a bank) changes their Terms and Conditions then they typically provide a high level summary of the changes, and then link to the complete T&C.  This is because it's not expected for everyone to remember every single line and read and accept the whole document from scratch; having a delta is good.

The [new CoC](/conduct) would kinda fall into the same space.  Not that I ever expect to fall foul (I will have seriously gone wrong if I do!) but having a summary of changes would be good.  Otherwise people will just glaze over the wall of text.

(If there is a summary and I didn't see it from the banner link then please let me know and I'll delete this!)

Comment: Related: [We are updating our Code of Conduct and we would like your feedback](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/1296614)

Comment: The main argument is that since the new CoC is a complete re-write, there's no practical way to give a list of changes.

Comment: `vimdiff <(elinks -no-references -no-numbering -dump https://web.archive.org/web/20230529124634/https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct) <(elinks -no-references -no-numbering -dump https://unix.stackexchange.com/conduct)` is not helping much.